# Formula for Bayesian A/B Testing doesn't make any sense

Tags: r, bayesian, ab-test

I'm using the formula from [Bayesian ab testing](http://www.evanmiller.org/bayesian-ab-testing.html) in order to compute results of AB test using Bayesian methodology.

$$ \Pr(p_B > p_A) = \sum^{\alpha_B-1}_{i=0} \frac{B(\alpha_A+i,\beta_B+\beta_A)}{(\beta_B+i)B(1+i,\beta_B)B(\alpha_A, \beta_A)} $$

where

- $\alpha_A$ in one plus the number of successes for A
- $\beta_A$ in one plus the number of failures for A
- $\alpha_B$ in one plus the number of successes for B
- $\beta_B$ in one plus the number of failures for B
- $B$ is the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Example data:

```
control: 1000 trials with 78 successes
test: 1000 trials with 100 successes
```

A standard non Bayesian prop test gives me  significant results (p < 10%):

```
prop.test(n=c(1000,1000), x=c(100,78), correct=F)

#   2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction
# 
# data:  c(100, 78) out of c(1000, 1000)
# X-squared = 2.9847, df = 1, p-value = 0.08405
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.0029398  0.0469398
# sample estimates:
# prop 1 prop 2 
#  0.100  0.078
```

while my implementation of the Bayes formula (using the explanations in the link) gave me very weird results:

```
# success control+1
a_control <- 78+1
# failures control+1
b_control <- 1000-78+1
# success control+1
a_test <- 100+1
# failures control+1
b_test <- 1000-100+1

is_control_better <- 0
for (i in 0:(a_test-1) ) {
  is_control_better <- is_control_better+beta(a_control+i,b_control+b_test) / 
                       (b_test+i)*beta(1+i,b_test)*beta(a_control,b_control)

}

round(is_control_better, 4)
# [1] 0
```

that means that that $P(TEST > CONTROL)$ is $0$, which doesn't make any sense given this data.

Could someone clarify?

Comment: A Bayesian analysis questiob with a `p-value` tag? I thought Bayesians refused to have anything to do with p-values.

Comment: Your right! just thought that it would attract more attention!

Comment: @YehoshaphatSchellekens if that was the real reason I remove the `p-value` tag since it is not related.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On the site you quote there is a notice

> The beta function produces very large numbers, so if you’re getting
>   infinite values in your program, be sure to work with logarithms, as
>   in the code above. Your standard library’s log-beta function will come
>   in handy here.

so your implementation is wrong. Below I provide the corrected code:

```
a_A <- 78+1
b_A <- 1000-78+1
a_B <- 100+1
b_B <- 1000-100+1

total <- 0

for (i in 0:(a_B-1) ) {
  total <- total + exp(lbeta(a_A+i, b_B+b_A)
                       - log(b_B+i)
                       - lbeta(1+i, b_B)
                       - lbeta(a_A, b_A))

}
```

It outputs total = 0.9576921, that is "odds that B will beat A in the long run" (quoting your link) what sounds valid since B in your example has greater proportion. So, it is *not* a *p*-value but rather a probability that B is greater then A (you do *not* expect it to be < 0.05).

You can run the simple simulations to check the results:

```
set.seed(123)

# does Binomial distributions with proportions
# from your data give similar estimates?

mean(rbinom(n, 1000, a_B/1000)>rbinom(n, 1000, a_A/1000))

# and does values simulated in a similar fashion to
# the model yield similar results?

fun2 <- function(n=1000) {
  pA <- rbeta(1, a_A, b_A)
  pB <- rbeta(1, a_B, b_B)
  mean(rbinom(n, 1000, pB) > rbinom(n, 1000, pA))
}

summary(replicate(1000, fun2(1000)))
```

In both cases the answer is yes.

---

As about the code, notice that for loop is unnecessary and generally they make things slower in R, so you can alternatively use `vapply` for cleaner and a little bit faster code:

```
fun <- function(i) exp(lbeta(a_A+i, b_B+b_A)
             - log(b_B+i)
             - lbeta(1+i, b_B)
             - lbeta(a_A, b_A))

sum(vapply(0:(a_B-1), fun, numeric(1)))
```

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if you actually tested for speed, because `vapply` is no more vectorozied than the `for` loop, on the contrary, they are basically the same. Nice answer though.

Comment: @DavidArenburg `vapply` is approximately 1.1 times faster. It is not much but generally if you can avoid for loops in R in most cases better do so.

Comment: @DavidArenburg *Any* vectorized function internally is a kind of loop... But ok, I changed the wording not to be confusing.

Comment: C/C++/Fortan `for` loops == vectorized; R `for` loop != vectorized. This is basically the definition of vectorized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this great vectorization discussion as well. @Tim , i did look at the log comment, but i thought R could handle it, guess not. ill use your code, for my needs, speed isn't important.

Comment: @YehoshaphatSchellekens the point with logs is not about certain software but general statistical computing. In the example on the site you quote julia code is provided - julia is also very good language for statistical programming and still logs are used.

Comment: Actually, I've just [asked a question regarding this exact discussion we had](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized) on SO, I may need to rethink my approach towards `vapply` in the future. I hope I'll get some nice answer once and for all.

Comment: Ok, after long thinking and summing up the comments and the answers I've received on my question, I think I came up with some general understanding of what `vapply` really is. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983292/is-the-apply-family-really-not-vectorized/29006276#29006276)