Is it possible to simulate random numbers from Beta-Binomial Distribution using a Beta Distribution and a Binomial Distribution?
It seems to me that a Beta-Binomial distribution can be thought of as following:

We simulate a random number from beta$(a,b)$ ... call this number $p_1$
We then take a Binomial distribution with success probability $p_1$ and see how many successes in $n$ trials

I tried to do this in R:
library(tidyverse)

generate_beta_samples <- function(n_samples, 
  alpha, beta) {
  p_values <- rbeta(n_samples, alpha, beta)
  
  data.frame(
    simulation = 1:n_samples,
    p = p_values
  )
}

generate_binomial_samples <- function(p_df, 
  n_trials) {
  p_df %>%
    mutate(
      successes = map_dbl(p, ~ rbinom(1, 
        size = n_trials, prob = .x))
    )
}

n_simulations <- 10000
n_trials <- 20
alpha <- 2
beta <- 5

set.seed(123)

beta_samples <- 
    generate_beta_samples(n_simulations, alpha, 
                            beta)

# Binomial samples
results <- generate_binomial_samples(beta_samples, n_trials)


p1 <- ggplot(results, aes(x = p)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 50, fill = "blue", 
   alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = alpha/(alpha + beta), 
          color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(
    title = 
 "Step 1: Distribution of Beta Random Variables",
    subtitle = paste0("Beta(", alpha, ",", beta, 
    ")"),
    x = "p",
    y = "Count"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()

p2 <- ggplot(results, aes(x = successes)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = n_trials + 1, 
  fill = "green", alpha = 0.6) +
  labs(
    title = 
  "Step 2: Distribution of Binomial Successes",
    subtitle = paste0(n_trials, 
     " trials for each p value"),
    x = "Number of Successes",
    y = "Count"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()


I also tried to look at the joint distribution:
ggplot(results, aes(x = p, y = successes)) +
    geom_bin2d(bins = 30) +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma", 
      name = "Count") +
    labs(
        title = 
 "Joint Distribution of Beta Values and Binomial Successes",
 subtitle = paste0("Beta(", alpha, ",", beta, ") 
 and Binomial(n=", n_trials, ") from ", 
 n_simulations, " simulations"),
        x = "p (Beta random variable)",
        y = 
   "Number of Successes (Binomial outcome)"
    ) +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, n_trials)) +
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(
       color = "gray90"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(
       color = "gray85"))


Is this the correct way to simulate a Beta-Binomial without using pre-built R functions?

The beta-binomial is a conjugate prior, meaning the output is also a beta distribution. Because it’s a closed form function of parameters alpha, and beta, you can sample from the posterior directly using numpy, scipy, etc.

Not Python but here’s a detailed and programmatic answer https://drvalle1.github.io/9_Conjugate_pairs_example.html

oh i think I understand

1)The Long Way (Frequentist):
100 students each flip the same coin 100 times. Before starting, we suspect the coin's probability of heads followed a Beta(2,2) distribution . Each student recorded their number of heads, giving 100 observations like: 48, 52, 51, 47...  then :
In the end, we estimate the probability of heads for the coin (point estimate).

2)The Short Way (Bayesian):
Start with Beta(2,2) prior. Then Add up all heads across all students: eg 5100 heads total and added up all tails: 4900 tails total.  My posterior is immediately Beta(2 + 5100, 2 + 4900) = Beta(5102, 4902). In the end, posterior distribution is Beta(5102, 4902), which tells us the probability of heads has a mean of 5102/(5102 + 4902) = 0.51, and we have the full probability distribution of our uncertainty about this estimate.

I think example explains the conjugate property you were talking about?

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147060/beta-binomial-distribution-with-r

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Generating_random_variates
