# In a Beta-Binomial 'Bayesian' A/B test, is it possible to add a third, fourth, etc. recipe?

Tags: bayesian, ab-test, beta-binomial-distribution

For context: [How to define prior for beta-binomial A/B test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180220/how-to-define-prior-for-beta-binomial-a-b-test)

For P(A > B), you can draw samples from A's posterior and B's posterior and then count the number of times the sample from A is greater than the sample from B. If choice C entered the picture, I don't intuitively see why:

```
mean(A_samp > B_samp & A_samp > C_samp)
```

wouldn't work, but I suspect that's a bit too simplistic. I'm not sure how to extend this to the n >= 3 case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [this blog entry](http://www.evanmiller.org/bayesian-ab-testing.html) by Evan Miller (mentioned in the link you refer to) describes case when you want to test the hypothesis that $A > \max(B,C)$ for binary and count data. It basically gives closed-form solution for what you are suggesting, so in fact there is not need to conduct simulation.

Notice however that since people mean often different things by A/B testing and if you mean that your data is counts of choices in multiple-choices scenario, then [Dirichlet-multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution) model would be more appropriate.