# Haldane's prior Beta(0,0) - Part 1

Tags: bayesian, prior, conjugate-prior, uninformative-prior, improper-prior

This [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.1067.pdf)$^1$ on p.16 specifies Haldane's prior as:

$$p(\theta) = \frac{1}{θ(1−θ)}$$.

However, [other](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.486.8021&rep=rep1&type=pdf)$^2$ source on p.6 specifies Haldane's prior as proportional to $\frac{1}{θ(1−θ)}$, i.e. 
$$p(\theta) \propto \frac{1}{θ(1−θ)}$$.

Could anyone clarify which expression is the accurate one.

[1. Approximation of improper priors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.1067.pdf)

[2. Bayesian Analysis of Some Common Distributions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.486.8021&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: This is an improper prior because its integral diverges.  Since it is improper, constants of proportionality have no relevance because no normalizing constant exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haldane prior is beta distribution with parameters $\alpha = \beta = 0$. So it is

$$
f(p) = \frac{p^{\alpha-1} (1-p)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)} = \frac{p^{-1}(1-p)^{-1}}{B(0, 0)}
$$

where $B(0, 0)$ is the normalizing constant that *is infinite* as [described in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Haldane's_prior_probability_(Beta(0,0))):

> The function $p^{-1}(1-p)^{-1}$ can be viewed as the limit of the
>   numerator of the beta distribution as both shape parameters approach
>   zero: $\alpha, \beta \to 0$. The Beta function (in the denominator of
>   the beta distribution) approaches infinity, for both parameters
>   approaching zero, $\alpha, \beta \to 0$. Therefore, $p^{-1}(1-p)^{-1}$
>   divided by the Beta function approaches a 2-point Bernoulli
>   distribution with equal probability $1/2$ at each Dirac delta function
>   end, at $0$ and $1$, and nothing in between, as $\alpha, \beta \to 0$.

So Haldane prior is not a proper distribution. It is an abstract idea of what would be the beta distribution be if it had $\alpha = \beta = 0$ parameters. As a distribution, it is rather not usable, yet it can be used as an ["uninformative" prior for binomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297901/choosing-between-uninformative-beta-priors/298176#298176). It is often described in it's approximate form $f(p) \propto p^{-1}(1-p)^{-1}$, since the normalizing constant is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks @Tim; can it be shown how the Beta function approaches $\infty$ as $\alpha, \beta→0$.

Comment: @AlexStat it follows from $\Gamma(0) = \infty$

Comment: @Tim: in which sense $f(p) \propto p^{-1}(1-p)^{-1}$ is approximate? There is no imprecision in defining the prior without a constant since all choices of a constant lead to the same posterior (if defined) or none( if undefined).

Comment: @Xi'an as a distribution it lacks the constant.

Comment: Imho, it is a measure (or the density of a measure against the Lebesgue measure onm $(0,1)$) rather than a distribution. As the [notion of distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2136584/14893) is not set outside "probability distributions".

Answer (score 4):

The second expression is correct as this is an improper distribution, i.e. it doesn't integrate to $1$. Thus it doesn't have a density and you can only specify it up to proportionality.